# Adding multiple options to a list

Tags: forms, lists, multi-selection, formatting

In my web app there is a section for users to add packages to send products to us. Currently, there is a blank package when the user first arrives at the screen.

[image: What the user first sees when coming to the screen.]

After filling out the package weight and details and clicking 'add package', the package is added to a list of packages in a list below.

[image: After adding a package]

If the user wants to add another package, they fill out the weight and package details again above and add it. Both weight and details are required so 'add package' can't be selected until both are filled out. It seems people are confused about how to add a second (or more) package after the first one has been added to the list. Is there a better way to handle adding multiple packages if the user happens to have more than one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could be a bit more structured - clear label to add another package that then brings up the 'add a package' module.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This works very well!

Answer (score 0):

You could add label "Add another package + " below the most recent package.

Option 1. Clicking "Add another package + " would make the "weight" input field active with a blinking text cursor prompting the user to begin the process

Option 2. Clicking "Add another package + " would trigger a pop up or overlay with "weight" and "details" input fields and add button to populate the "list of packages"

Prompting and guiding a new user is paramount, even if you have to duplicate the process. Eventually they will automatically complete the "add package" form you have provided.

Hope this helps